# Flask - Render a select field with flask-wtforms and QuerySelect

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to render a form that contains 3 text field and a select field. I can render the text fields with data from database but not the select field.
The select field has to present as selected option the data coming from the database and the other choices.
I'm using:
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12

This is the code:

#### View

```
@app.route('/gateway/edit/<int:gwt_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def gateway_edit(gwt_id):
    q = Device.query.filter_by(gtw_id=gwt_id).first()
    form = Gateway(obj=q)
    form.populate_obj(q)
    return render_template('gateway.html', form=form)
```

#### Model

```
class Gateway(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "gateway"
    gateway_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gateway_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    gateway_desc = db.Column(db.String(64))
    devices = db.relationship('Device', backref='gateway', lazy='dynamic')



class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "device"
    device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    device_desc = db.Column(db.String(64))
    gateway_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('gateway.gateway_id'))
    device_ip = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

#### form

```
class Gateway(Form):
    gateway_name = StringField('Gateway Name')
    gateway_desc = TextAreaField('Gateway Description')

def gtws():
    return Gateway.query

class Device(Form):
    device_name = StringField('Device Name')
    device_desc = TextAreaField('Device Description')
    device_ip = StringField('Device IP')
    gtw_group = QuerySelectField('Gateway',query_factory=gtws)
```

#### Template

```
{{ render_field(form.device_name, class="form-control")}}
{{ render_field(form.device_desc, class="form-control")}}
{{ render_field(form.device_ip, class="form-control")}}
{{ render_field(form.gtw_group, class="form-control")}}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I misunderstood the backref in model. It creates a virtual column in my Device model. Then I can associate the form field (in my case the QuerySelectField) using this virtual column name.

I did some simple changes in the code:
**Model**

```
devices = db.relationship('Device', backref='gtw', lazy='dynamic')
```

**Form**

```
gtw = QuerySelectField('Gateway',query_factory=gtws)
```

**Template**

```
{{ render_field(form.gtw, class="form-control")}}
```